# Add btrfs devices to raid1 array, increasing total size

Tags: raid1, raid10, btrfs

I have a btrfs array comprising of two 2TB disks in raid 1. I am running out of space, and I want to add two 3TB disks that I have lying around. The final setup will be 2x2TB+2x3TB drives. One drive failure redundancy is sufficient for me (the data is backed up somewhere else too).

I am unsure how to proceed: the [btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Adding_new_devices) clearly states how to add new devices, but I am unsure how this will end up looking in terms of available disck space. Will I end up with:

1. 2TB of space with 4x redundancy or
2. 4TB of space with 2x redundancy or
3. something else?

Based on some research (e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438199/btrfs-did-i-just-turn-raid1-into-raid10) answer) I think the outcome should be 2, which is what I would want. Is this correct?

Another possibility is that I switch to a raid 10 setup, if this is possible with disks of different size. If this is advisable, how should I do so without temporarily hosting the data on external storage?

Comment: I would have hoped this would get me 2x5Tb...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 2TB of space with 4x redundancy or

A quote from official wiki explains it in details:

"… btrfs combines all the devices into a storage pool first, and then duplicates the chunks as file data is created.

RAID-1 is defined currently as "2 copies of all the data on different devices".

This differs from MD-RAID and dmraid …"

— 2 copies only.

> Another possibility is that I switch to a raid 10 setup, if this is possible with disks of different size.

Again reading same source: "…

*RAID-10 is built on top of these definitions.*

Every stripe is split across to exactly 2 RAID-1 sets and those RAID-1 sets are written to exactly 2 devices (hence 4 devices minimum). A btrfs RAID-10 volume with 6 × 1 TB devices will yield 3 TB usable space with 2 copies of all data. …"

> how should I do so without temporarily hosting the data on external storage?

It's all explained as well in "Conversion" paragraph — starting `btrfs balance` over a mount point with specifications of needed profile for data and metadata. Trivially adjusting theirs example it becomes this:

`btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid10 -mconvert=raid10 /…mntPoint…`

I suppose there's no need in intermediate `balance` after you'd have two new disks added into that pool — addition itself won't do re-balance, only newly written data would use additional devices. Therefore, it's pretty trivial: add and start balance to any of the layout you're liking.

---

#### Conclusion

Theoretically you would have the best possible outcome because "*btrfs combines all the devices into a storage pool first*"

#### Practice

It would be very simple to test all this using a setup on, say, loopback devices of much smaller sizes.

#### A word of caution

In despite Btrfs became pretty mature I heard that multiple device support still isn't robust enough compared to non-RAID-like mode. I'd recommend trying mentioned above conversion on loopback devices first *and even if it would go successfully, backuping at least most important data somewhere else*.

Also, expressing my own opinion I'd say that I'd prefer converting such a setup into traditional LVM-2 over LSR (Linux Software RAID aka MD) that would give you ability to create logical sub-volumes for later use either with Btrfs or any other desired FS.